# Windows Server 2008 R2 + IIS 7.5 + ASP.NET 4.0 = HTTP Error 500.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I am having an impossible time getting asp.net 4.0 to work in any fashion at all.  In fact, I completely wiped my server, reinstalled with Server 2008 R2 Standard (running on a VMWare ESXi box, not that it should matter), and cannot even get a test .aspx page to work.

Here is exactly what I did:

1. Installed 2008 R2 Standard
2. Activated windows and enabled Remote Desktop
3. Installed the Web Server Role with the necessary role services(common http, asp.net, logging, tracing, management service and FTP)
4. Enabled the management service
5. Installed .Net Framework 4.0 via web executable
6. Added FTP publishing to the default web site
7. Switched default web site application pool to asp.net 4.0 (integrated)
8. Added a 'test.aspx' file to the inetpub\wwwroot folder (contents below)
9. Opened a browser to http://localhost/test.aspx and received a 500.0 error (also below)

What am I missing?  I haven't touched IIS in a while (3+ years), so it could be something stupid/trvial.  Please point it out, call me a noob; my ego can take it.

Thanks,
Dave

test.aspx

> ```
> <% @Page language="C# %>
>  <html>
>  <head>
>     <title>Test.aspx</title>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>     <asp:label runat="server" text="This is an asp.net 4.0 label" />
>  </body>
>  </html>
> ```

Error page:

```
Module  AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/test.aspx
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.aspx
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
```

Trace:

And in my trace file I get:

```
96. view trace Warning -SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_DESCRIPTION 
ErrorDescription An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.


97. view trace Warning -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule 
Notification 1 
HttpStatus 500 
HttpReason Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 2147942402 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification BEGIN_REQUEST 
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)
```

The application error log shows:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP
Date:          5/28/2010 2:08:10 PM
Event ID:      2299
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      win-ltfkdo1dnfp
Description:
An application has reported as being unhealthy. The worker process will now request a recycle. Reason given: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur. The data is the error.   

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP" Guid="{670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD}" EventSourceName="W3SVC-WP" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">2299</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-05-28T21:08:10.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1663</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>win-ltfkdo1dnfp</Computer>
    <Security />
 </System>
 <EventData>
 <Data Name="Reason">An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
 </Data>
    <Binary>02000780</Binary>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem on iis7.5 win2008 R2 x64 with .net 4.0.

Anyone found a solution to this...I have tried everything I can think of!

Comment: restarted the server which seems to have fixed it...seems to fix most windows issues!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this same problem while using Reflector to debug external assemblies.

The program messed with my `DEVPATH` environment variable and I saw the same symptoms as described here.
Resetting (emptying) the `DEVPATH` solved the issue here.

Seems unrelated, but it would be so obscure to find that this is the problem in the OP's case that I think it's worth reporting.

Comment: Yup, that was indeed the issue in my case as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be strange.. but doing the above alone and what all other sites (links below) said about application.host file changes or executing iisreg on framework and framework64 folder .. didnt fix a similar problem for me.

My application probably had some 32 bit dependencies which were also causing the above error (instead of saying wrong binary format as it happens usually)
I changed my application pool to allow 32 bit mode (WoW mode) and then I got the binary format problem reported..which I then fixed to solve the problems

Other sites that had suggestions:

- [Solving Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated has a bad module ManagedPipelineHandler in ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2010/07/12/solving-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-asp-net-4-0/)
- [HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/justtrace/general-discussions/http-error-500-0---internal-server-error.aspx)